# SpringBoot and hikari log database connection acquire and release

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I'm using springboot+hikari+hibernate to build a rest API.
Some queries are really have and the database is really polluted and worst, there is a clear connection leak.

This is a legacy system which I wasn't part of design nor development but I need to do maintenance and I would like to debug where is the connection leak.

As far as I can see all transactions are annotated @Transaction... so there shouldn't be any connection "forgotten open"...

Is there any way for me to build a configuration class or annotate a method with something in order to be invoked right before any thread request a connection and right after the thread releases it? This way I could try to trace where is the leak source.

I've this settings on

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold=60000
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

But this generates a very verbose log output and this system is in production so is almost impossible to track the problem.... I would like to create just a method for every connection acquire and release so I could myself write the log and find the source.

Comment: I believe that if you set `logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=WARN` you'll see information about leaked connections. But I haven't tried this, so not an answer.

Comment: @Rafael Lima Have you found any solution for this? If you could share, it will be helpful. Thanks in Advance!